# looping over a byte array to convert 64 bit to decimal

Tags: arrays, loops, type-conversion, byte

I have an extremely large file filled with 8 byte double precision data.

I've created this loop to convert all the data to decimal but I keep getting a
TypeError: 'bytearray' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Any tips?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import struct

#import file
f=open('nohead.stk','rb')

#Read in the data as a byte array (8-bit array)
ba = bytearray(f.read())
#number of bytes in the data file
length = len(ba)
print('N-bytes=',length)
#Since the data is in 64bits, convert eight bits at a time to a 64 bit
#Number of data points in file
nvals = int(length/8);
print('N-recordings for 64bits (8-byte data)=',nvals)

#loop over all values
for i in range(nvals):
    eightbytes[i] = ba[(i*8):(8+i*8)]
    unpacked[i] = struct.unpack('<d', eightbytes[i])[0]
    

f= open("Reading_Decimal.csv","w+")

f.write("%f\n" % (unpacked[i]))
f.close();
```

I've attached the first 24 bytes here so you can save it to a file and see if you can get the loop to work on the first 3 decimals

should be around -6

bytearray(b'\xef,\x81\xb6\\xf1\x17\xc0\xff\xe0\x9b\x80\xb6\xeb\x17\xc0\xbd\x98V\xb0\xbd\xa3\x17\xc0')

cheers

Comment: Nothing in your code will throw that error. Are you sure you copied the actual code you're running?

Comment: yep its the exact code, issue arises at the loop

Comment: Except it doesn't. Works fine.

Comment: it works fine for you? are you able to get all three values out??

Comment: Yes. Your code is suspicious. For example how are you declaring eightbytes and unpacked lists. It's obviously not what you're running. If it were it would complain 'eightbytes' or 'unpacked' is not defined. You should check again.

Comment: yeah i had a bunch of other stuff in there before and when i went back in it now its coming up with eightbytes and unpacked not defined. when i set up an empty array for eightbytes it gives me ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: what did you edit to get it to run for you?

Answer (score 0):

got the answer myself

hopefully this may help others

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import struct

#import file with no headers
f=open('15_stack_noheaders.stk','rb')

#Read in the data as a byte array (8-bit array)
ba = bytearray(f.read())
bs=str(ba)
#number of bytes in the data file
length = len(ba)
print('N-bytes=',length)
#Since the data is in 64bits, convert eight bits at a time to a 64 bit
#Number of data points in file
nvals = int(length/8);
print('N-recordings for 64bits (8-byte data)=',nvals)

#create empty array of zeros to fill
dat = np.zeros(nvals)

for i in range(0,nvals):
    dat[i] = struct.unpack('<d',ba[8*i:8+i*8])[0]

f= open("output.csv","w+")

for i in range(nvals) :
    f.write("%f\n" % (dat[i]))
f.close();
```